# How do I share a single iTunes library amongst multiple Window 8 accounts on the same PC?

Tags: windows-8, itunes

I have a new Windows 8 computer with two user accounts configured.

How do I share a single iTunes library amongst multiple Window 8 accounts on the same PC?

Comment: I would think moving the library to be contained with the `Public` user profile would solve this problem.  Of course multiple iTunes account will be unable to use any content owned by another iTunes account.